# How to send a message to a text channel when a user joins a voice channel in Discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to write a Discord bot using Python that sends a message to a specific text channel when a user joins a specific voice channel. I have tried the following code, but it doesn’t seem to be working:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&', intents=intents)
channel = bot.get_channel(#there is channel id)

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel and after.channel and discord.VoiceChannel.id in [#there is list of channels]:
        channel.send('message')
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should try yourself instead of asking a question with "*idk how to...*" you don't think?

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this

```py
# after setting up the bot
channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  # this will trigger if the member is not in a voice channel and join specific voice channel
  if not before.channel and after.channel and after.channel.id in LIST_OF_SPECIFIED_CHANNELS:
    await channel.send("some text")
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `on_voice_state_update` function, you are calling the `send` method on the `channel` object without using the `await` keyword. This means that the `send` method is not being executed as a coroutine, and the message is not being sent to the text channel.

Replace `channel.send('message')` with `await channel.send('message')`